# Scrapy exporting weird symbols into csv file

Tags: python, encoding, scrapy

Ok, so here's the issue. I'm a beginner who has just started to delve into scrapy/python.

I use the code below to scrape a website and save the results into a csv. When I look in the command prompt, it turns words like Officiële into Offici\xele. In the csv file, it changes it to officiÃ«le. I think this is because it's saving in unicode instead of UTF-8? I however have 0 clue how to change my code, and I've been trying all morning so far.

Could anyone help me out here? I'm specifically looking at making sure item["publicatietype"] works properly. How can I encode/decode it? What do I need to write? I tried using replace('Ã«', 'ë'), but that gives me an error (non-ASCCI character, but no encoding declared).

```
class pagespider(Spider):
    name = "OBSpider"
    #max_page is put here to prevent endless loops; make it as large as you need. It will try and go up to that page
    #even if there's nothing there. A number too high will just take way too much time and yield no results
    max_pages = 1

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.max_pages):
            yield scrapy.Request("https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/zoeken/resultaat/?zkt=Uitgebreid&pst=Tractatenblad|Staatsblad|Staatscourant|BladGemeenschappelijkeRegeling|ParlementaireDocumenten&vrt=Cybersecurity&zkd=InDeGeheleText&dpr=Alle&sdt=general_informationPublicatie&ap=&pnr=18&rpp=10&_page=%d&sorttype=1&sortorder=4" % (i+1), callback = self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class = "lijst"]/ul/li'):
            item = ThingsToGather()
            item["titel"] = ' '.join(sel.xpath('a/text()').extract())
            deeplink = ''.join(["https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/", ' '.join(sel.xpath('a/@href').extract())])
            request = scrapy.Request(deeplink, callback=self.get_page_info)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def get_page_info(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="Inhoud"]'):
            item = response.meta['item']

    #it loads some general info from the header. If this string is less than 5 characters, the site probably is a faulthy link (i.e. an error 404). If this is the case, then it drops the item. Else it continues

            if len(' '.join(sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "logo-nummer")]/div[contains(@class, "nummer")]/text()').extract())) < 5:
                raise DropItem()
            else:
                item["filename"] = ' '.join(sel.xpath('//*[@id="downloadPdfHyperLink"]/@href').extract())
                item['publicatiedatum'] = sel.xpath('//span[contains(@property, "http://purl.org/dc/terms/available")]/text()').extract()
                item["publicatietype"] = sel.xpath('//span[contains(@property, "http://purl.org/dc/terms/type")]/text()').extract()
                item["filename"] = ' '.join(sel.xpath('//*[@id="downloadPdfHyperLink"]/@href').extract())
                item = self.__normalise_item(item, response.url)

    #if the string is less than 5, then the required data is not on the page. It then needs to be
    #retrieved from the technical information link. If it's the proper link (the else clause), you're done and it proceeds to 'else'
                if len(item['publicatiedatum']) < 5:
                    tech_inf_link = ''.join(["https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/", ' '.join(sel.xpath('//*[@id="technischeInfoHyperlink"]/@href').extract())])
                    request = scrapy.Request(tech_inf_link, callback=self.get_date_info)
                    request.meta['item'] = item
                    yield request 
                else:
                    yield item

    def get_date_info (self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="Inhoud"]'):
            item = response.meta['item']
            item["filename"] = sel.xpath('//span[contains(@property, "http://standaarden.overheid.nl/oep/meta/publicationName")]/text()').extract()
            item['publicatiedatum'] = sel.xpath('//span[contains(@property, "http://purl.org/dc/terms/available")]/text()').extract()
            item['publicatietype'] = sel.xpath('//span[contains(@property, "http://purl.org/dc/terms/type")]/text()').extract()
            item["filename"] = ' '.join(sel.xpath('//*[@id="downloadPdfHyperLink"]/@href').extract())
            item = self.__normalise_item(item, response.url)    
            return item

    # commands below are intended to clean up strings. Everything is sent to __normalise_item to clean unwanted characters (strip) and double spaces (split)

    def __normalise_item(self, item, base_url):
        for key, value in vars(item).values()[0].iteritems():
            item[key] = self.__normalise(item[key])

        item ['titel']= item['titel'].replace(';', '& ')
        return item

    def __normalise(self, value):
        value = value if type(value) is not list else ' '.join(value)
        value = value.strip()
        value = " ".join(value.split())
        return value
```

ANSWER:

See comment by paul trmbrth below. The problem is not scrapy, it's excel.

For anyone coming across this question as well. The tldr is: import the data in excel (in the data menu in the ribbon) and switch Windows (ANSI) or whatever it is on to Unicode (UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

`Officiële` will be represented as `u'Offici\xeble'` in Python 2, as seen in the python shell session example below (no need to worry about the `\xXX` characters, it's just how Python represents non-ASCII Unicode characters)

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> u'Officiële'
u'Offici\xeble'
>>> u'Offici\u00EBle'
u'Offici\xeble'
>>>
```

> I think this is because it's saving in unicode instead of UTF-8

**UTF-8** is an encoding, *Unicode* is not.

`ë`, a.k.a `U+00EB`, a.k.a `LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS`, will be UTF-8 encoded as 2 bytes, `\xc3` and `\xab`

```
>>> u'Officiële'.encode('UTF-8')
'Offici\xc3\xable'
>>>
```

> In the csv file, it changes it to officiÃ«le.

If you see this, it's probably that you need to set the input encoding to UTF-8 when opening the CSV file inside your program.

Scrapy CSV exporter will write Python Unicode strings as UTF-8 encoded strings in the output file.

Scrapy selectors will output Unicode strings:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/zoeken/resultaat/?zkt=Uitgebreid&pst=Tractatenblad|Staatsblad|Staatscourant|BladGemeenschappelijkeRegeling|ParlementaireDocumenten&vrt=Cybersecurity&zkd=InDeGeheleText&dpr=Alle&sdt=general_informationPublicatie&ap=&pnr=18&rpp=10&_page=1&sorttype=1&sortorder=4"
2016-03-15 10:44:51 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2016-03-15 10:44:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/zoeken/resultaat/?zkt=Uitgebreid&pst=Tractatenblad|Staatsblad|Staatscourant|BladGemeenschappelijkeRegeling|ParlementaireDocumenten&vrt=Cybersecurity&zkd=InDeGeheleText&dpr=Alle&sdt=general_informationPublicatie&ap=&pnr=18&rpp=10&_page=1&sorttype=1&sortorder=4> (referer: None)
(...)
In [1]: response.css('div.menu-bmslink > ul > li > a::text').extract()
Out[1]: 
[u'Offici\xeble bekendmakingen vandaag',
 u'Uitleg nieuwe nummering Handelingen vanaf 1 januari 2011',
 u'Uitleg nieuwe\r\n            nummering Staatscourant vanaf 1 juli 2009']

In [2]: for t in response.css('div.menu-bmslink > ul > li > a::text').extract():
    print t
   ...:     
Officiële bekendmakingen vandaag
Uitleg nieuwe nummering Handelingen vanaf 1 januari 2011
Uitleg nieuwe
            nummering Staatscourant vanaf 1 juli 2009
```

Let's see what a spider extracting these strings in items will get you as CSV:

```
$ cat testspider.py
import scrapy


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'testspider'
    start_urls = ['https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/zoeken/resultaat/?zkt=Uitgebreid&pst=Tractatenblad|Staatsblad|Staatscourant|BladGemeenschappelijkeRegeling|ParlementaireDocumenten&vrt=Cybersecurity&zkd=InDeGeheleText&dpr=Alle&sdt=general_informationPublicatie&ap=&pnr=18&rpp=10&_page=1&sorttype=1&sortorder=4']

    def parse(self, response):
        for t in response.css('div.menu-bmslink > ul > li > a::text').extract():
            yield {"link": t}
```

Run the spider and ask for CSV output:

```
$ scrapy runspider testspider.py -o test.csv
2016-03-15 11:00:13 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-03-15 11:00:13 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-03-15 11:00:13 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'test.csv'}
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/zoeken/resultaat/?zkt=Uitgebreid&pst=Tractatenblad|Staatsblad|Staatscourant|BladGemeenschappelijkeRegeling|ParlementaireDocumenten&vrt=Cybersecurity&zkd=InDeGeheleText&dpr=Alle&sdt=general_informationPublicatie&ap=&pnr=18&rpp=10&_page=1&sorttype=1&sortorder=4> (referer: None)
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/zoeken/resultaat/?zkt=Uitgebreid&pst=Tractatenblad|Staatsblad|Staatscourant|BladGemeenschappelijkeRegeling|ParlementaireDocumenten&vrt=Cybersecurity&zkd=InDeGeheleText&dpr=Alle&sdt=general_informationPublicatie&ap=&pnr=18&rpp=10&_page=1&sorttype=1&sortorder=4>
{'link': u'Offici\xeble bekendmakingen vandaag'}
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/zoeken/resultaat/?zkt=Uitgebreid&pst=Tractatenblad|Staatsblad|Staatscourant|BladGemeenschappelijkeRegeling|ParlementaireDocumenten&vrt=Cybersecurity&zkd=InDeGeheleText&dpr=Alle&sdt=general_informationPublicatie&ap=&pnr=18&rpp=10&_page=1&sorttype=1&sortorder=4>
{'link': u'Uitleg nieuwe nummering Handelingen vanaf 1 januari 2011'}
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/zoeken/resultaat/?zkt=Uitgebreid&pst=Tractatenblad|Staatsblad|Staatscourant|BladGemeenschappelijkeRegeling|ParlementaireDocumenten&vrt=Cybersecurity&zkd=InDeGeheleText&dpr=Alle&sdt=general_informationPublicatie&ap=&pnr=18&rpp=10&_page=1&sorttype=1&sortorder=4>
{'link': u'Uitleg nieuwe\r\n            nummering Staatscourant vanaf 1 juli 2009'}
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Stored csv feed (3 items) in: test.csv
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 488,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 12018,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 15, 10, 0, 14, 991735),
 'item_scraped_count': 3,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 15, 10, 0, 14, 59471)}
2016-03-15 11:00:14 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Check content of CSV file:

```
$ cat test.csv
link
Officiële bekendmakingen vandaag
Uitleg nieuwe nummering Handelingen vanaf 1 januari 2011
"Uitleg nieuwe
            nummering Staatscourant vanaf 1 juli 2009"
$ hexdump -C test.csv 
00000000  6c 69 6e 6b 0d 0a 4f 66  66 69 63 69 c3 ab 6c 65  |link..Offici..le|
00000010  20 62 65 6b 65 6e 64 6d  61 6b 69 6e 67 65 6e 20  | bekendmakingen |
00000020  76 61 6e 64 61 61 67 0d  0a 55 69 74 6c 65 67 20  |vandaag..Uitleg |
00000030  6e 69 65 75 77 65 20 6e  75 6d 6d 65 72 69 6e 67  |nieuwe nummering|
00000040  20 48 61 6e 64 65 6c 69  6e 67 65 6e 20 76 61 6e  | Handelingen van|
00000050  61 66 20 31 20 6a 61 6e  75 61 72 69 20 32 30 31  |af 1 januari 201|
00000060  31 0d 0a 22 55 69 74 6c  65 67 20 6e 69 65 75 77  |1.."Uitleg nieuw|
00000070  65 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 6e  |e..            n|
00000080  75 6d 6d 65 72 69 6e 67  20 53 74 61 61 74 73 63  |ummering Staatsc|
00000090  6f 75 72 61 6e 74 20 76  61 6e 61 66 20 31 20 6a  |ourant vanaf 1 j|
000000a0  75 6c 69 20 32 30 30 39  22 0d 0a                 |uli 2009"..|
000000ab
```

You can verify that `ë` is correctly encoded as `c3 ab`

I can see the file data correctly when using LibreOffice for example (notice "Character set: Unicode UTF-8"):

[image: Opening test.csv in LibreOffice]

You are probably using Latin-1. Here's what you get when using Latin-1 instead of UTF-8 as input encoding setting (in LibreOffice again):

[image]

Comment: Wow, you're a hero. I never realized the problem could be excel. Oh, I feel so silly haha.

For anyone coming across this question as well. The tldr is: import the data in excel (in the data menu in the ribbon) and switch Windows (ANSI) or whatever it is on to Unicode (UTF-8). This seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

To encode a string you can directly use `encode("utf-8")` . Something like this:

```
item['publicatiedatum'] = ''.join(sel.xpath('//span[contains(@property, "http://purl.org/dc/terms/available")]/text()').extract()).encode("utf-8")
```