# Unicode issue in scrapy python

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

For two hours, I am searching for this topic and I have tried a lot of solutions but noen worked in my case
Here's the code first

```
import scrapy

class HamburgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hamburg'
    #allowed_domains = ['https://www.hamburg.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.hamburg.de/branchenbuch/hamburg/10239785/n0/']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_EXPORT_FORMAT': 'utf-8'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        #response=response.body.encode('utf-8')
        items = response.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'item')]")
        for item in items:
            business_name = item.xpath(".//h3[@class='h3rb']/text()").get()
            address1 = item.xpath(".//div[@class='address']/p[@class='extra post']/text()[1]").get()
            address2 = item.xpath(".//div[@class='address']/p[@class='extra post']/text()[2]").get()
            phone = item.xpath(".//div[@class='address']/span[@class='extra phone']/text()").get()

            yield {
                'Business Name': business_name,
                'Address1': address1,
                'Address2': address2,
                'Phone Number': phone
            }
```

In the code I put this line

custom_settings = {
'FEED_EXPORT_FORMAT': 'utf-8'
}

The line supposed to deal with the issue of encoding but when exporting the results to csv, I found that the issue is still there.
I simply need to show this example of text `Poppenbütteler Bogen 29a` sa shown on the website. What I found is that the output is different

Comment: I didn't use scrapy before, but how about `response.body = six.ensure_str(response.body)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It doesn't work at all and the output.csv is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong setting name.

`FEED_EXPORT_FORMAT` is not one of the settings scrapy uses by default, you want [FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried using `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING` but the output.csv is the same weird .. and not as expected. Have you tried the code on your side?

Comment: I tried opening the csv file using notepad++ and it works well. but not as expected when opening with excel. How can I display it properly on excel?

Comment: I think you'll have to use excel's data import functionality and specify the correct encoding (utf-8) there. Excel probably has some silly windowsy default.

Comment: Is there a way to export the scrapy results to CSV UTF8 instead of CSV only? Would I add the settings FORMAT too?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no separate "CSV UTF8" format, your file is a CSV, and it's utf8 encoded. The problem is Excel is *not* expecting it to be utf8 encoded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I use Pandas package to solve such a problem or it is not compatible with Scrapy. Can you help me with that point?

Comment: I don't see how Pandas would help. According to the internet (I don't have Excel on this machine to test), Excel needs BOM to correctly detect utf8 encoding, so try setting the encoding to `utf-8-sig` instead.

Comment: You are a rock. That does the trick using `utf-8-sig`. Thanks a lot for great support. Please add this to the answer so as to be a source for learners.

Comment: I don't think that's needed, since the question is strictly about the python/scrapy part, and this is an excel specific problem...